# Concatenate Multiple Data Files

Tags: python, c++, shell, sed, text-files

I have several data files that look like this:

```
HR0
012312010
001230202

HR1
012031020
012320102
012323222
012321010

HR2
321020202
...
```

To explain: there is a line that defines the field (HR"n"), a variable number of lines with quaternary numbers (321020202) and then an extra newline between two fields. I want to combine equivalent HR fields. So in a sense, I want to zipper these files into one large file. I think using sed is the answer, but I don't know where to start.

And I'm thinking of using a shell script over python or a c++ program because I feel it might be faster in both writing and execution. Thoughts?

Comment: Premature optimization. Compiled C++ program would be the fastest.

Comment: How do you want to handle collisions? what if there are 2 000000013 elements in different files HR0s?

Comment: @JonathanMee All elements are unique because of how the data is created. So there won't be any need for checking for that, if I understand your question correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty easy to do in C++, made more so if you have C++17.
You can write a function for reading a `multimap<int, int>` something like:

```
multimap<int, int> read(istream& input) {
    multimap<int, int> output;
    string i;

    while(input >> i) {
        const auto key = std::atoi(data(i) + 2);

        transform(istream_iterator<int>(input), istream_iterator<int>(), inserter(output, begin(output)), [key](const auto value){ return make_pair(key, value); });
        input.clear();
    }
    return output; 
}
```

So you'll call that function with each file's `ifstream` and use [`merge`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap/merge) to dump the return into your acumulating `multimap<int, int> output`.

Then you'll just dump `output` to your output file, say it had been opened with `ofstream filep` you could dump like this:

```
auto key = cbegin(output)->first;

filep << key << ":\n" << setfill('0');

for(const auto& it : output) {
    if(it.first == key) {
        filep << '\t' << setw(9) << it.second << endl;
    } else {
        key = it.first;
        filep << key << ":\n\t" << setw(9) << it.second << endl;
    }
}
```

I've written a live example only involving one file here: http://ideone.com/n47MnS

Comment: Wow, that is fantastic! Thank you so much!!

Comment: @Jeff Yup, C++11/14/17 have advanced the language so much that it is now very competitive with Python and scripting languages for ease of use, yet retains the low level power that C++ has always been revered for. Anyway... If this solves your problem I'd appreciate an accept.