# How can I use an istream_iterator Without the Need to Reset my Stream?

Tags: c++, stream, integer, istream, istream-iterator

I've written this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40181583/2642059 which uses an `istream_iterator<int>` to read in integers after its containing loop reads in the header. So the text is coming in formatted like this:

> HR0
>   012312010
>   001230202
>
> HR1
>   012031020
>   012320102
>   012323222
>   012321010
>
> HR2
>   321020202

I have that text in: `istringstream input`. I want to be able to read the integers using an `istream_iterator<int>(input)`, but that will read until it finds a non-`int` *and then set the bad bit on `input`*.

Is there a way I can avoid that, or do I just have to clear the bad bit each time my `istream_iterator<int>` concludes reading?

Comment: Why are you even reading this into a integer type?  `std::string` looks more appropriate since data like `001230202` is going to lose its leading zeros as a integer.

Comment: @NathanOliver As usual I skimped on putting my actual code in the answer. You can see it if you follow the link, if you think I should put it in there I will. That's just an integer with a fixed width.